# Cursor disappears in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, tinymce

I'm writing a web application that uses tinymce to edit documents.  In my web application, there is support for drag/drop to insert links to files saved in the system.

The issue I have is when I try to insert a link into a tinymce document in Firefox.  When I drag a file from my file viewer and drop it into the document, the document inserts the link, but the cursor disappears inside the document.  I can, however, type from where the cursor should be.  The only way to get the cursor to reappear, is to click else where in the application and then click back into the document.

My code for adding a link on drop is:

```
 function addLink(id, contentType, text)
    {
        var link = " <a href='#open:" + contentType + "%20" + id + "'>" + text + "</a>";
        tinymce.get("myDocPage").execCommand("mceInsertContent", false, link);
    }
```

After stepping through the code of tinymce, I had discovered that the execCommand has an undocumented 4th parameter.  It is a config object to handle various options of the command to execute, such as whether the document being modified should gain focus.  So I replace the second line above with:

```
tinymce.get("myDocPage").execCommand("mceInsertContent", false, link, {skip_focus: true});
```

After doing this, I can just click back into the document and the cursor appears but the edit starts at the newly placed link and all new text will be part of the link.

None of the above behavior happens in Chrome.  Chrome properly handles the insert and changes focus to the document with the cursor present.

Has anyone come across this issue before?  If so, how was it fixed or is there a workaround?  It seems that Firefox isn't handling the focus correctly.

Below is link to a js fiddle that shows the issue.
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/O3daab/1

Comment: Have you solved that?

Comment: Recently we found a workaround.   We added a floating div over the area that represents the drop zone.  The issue was related to the way Firefox handled drag/drop focus.  By adding a div that worked like a mask, we could listen on that div's drop and handle the links accordingly.  The trick is to only add the mask on drag over and remove it when you are done.  This will prevent the weird focus issues.